# Sentence structure wording

Tags: grammar

Are the following sentences both correct? Would there be a better way of wording the sentence?

> 1. You are now allowed to officially eat dinner.
> 2. You are now officially allowed to eat dinner.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Most likely, the allowance is official, not the eating, so the second one is correct.

Comment: Either one seems fine

Comment: Questions which lack results of research are out of scope.
Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Proofreading requests are out of scope.
Questions that invite many equally valid answers are out of scope.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 2):

With the split infinitive, the syntactic attraction of the **adverb** is to the infinitive. Compare

> You are now allowed to **quickly** eat dinner.

This gives you permission to gobble your food. But the semantic attraction of *officially* to the permission granted by *allowed* is strong enough that it's unlikely anyone would interpret the sentence to mean that the eating was official.

Comment: I agree "You are now allowed to officially eat dinner" will not confuse anyone, but would anyone in their right mind use this sentence? I think this sentence is wrong.

Comment: @Rathony If it wouldn't confuse anyone, why exactly is it wrong? And if it's wrong somehow, why would someone who thus erred have to be crazy? I'd  move the adverb before *allowed* because that avoids some silliness from the syntactic attraction I mentioned.

Comment: Well, I think the split infinitive rule is still applicable to an adverb like "officially" when it is used between "to" and "eat". The whole point of this rule is to prevent such construction that not only sounds silly, but also *ungrammatical*. Oh, is there a better word for *ungrammatical* here?

Comment: @Rathony But it's not ungrammatical. Grammar has nothing to do with how silly something sounds. That's semantics

Answer (score 1):

People would know what you mean. However, one of the sentences sounds a little strange. Here's why...

> "You are now allowed to officially eat dinner."

**This is not preferred**.

In this sentence, "officially" modifies "eat". That's because the two words are next to each other. So then, how do you eat officially? You can eat quickly. You can eat happily. But in what way can eating be official? The image is of a diplomat eating an official piece of cake, using a special fork of the diplomatic corps. This is a weird image so people would ignore the placement of the word "officially".

> "You are now officially allowed to eat dinner."

**This is better**.

"Officially" modifies "allowed". The two words are next to each other. The meaning is shifted to say that according to some official rule or authority, it's now OK to eat.

Answer (score 0):

Why use "officially"?

Also, "allowed" seems out of place for entertaining unless you're speaking to prisoners.

**You may now eat dinner.**

**Dinner is served.**

**We will now commence with the evening meal.**

Of the three, the middle sentence is the most commonly used in America for various receptions, and everyone understands it's time to eat.

Comment: Very true, and the best advice. But not an 'answer' here.